# MySQL convert month number to month name

Tags: mysql, date, date-conversion

Is it possible to convert an integer/column to month name in MySQL?
For example, 1 becomes 'Jan' or 'January'. 13 and onwards give an error, or will be never used.

Comment: I think a simple Google search would get you the answer. Or just browse the MySQL date functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- We can convert the given input number to MySQL date format (focusing on month only), using [`Str_To_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.
- Now, we simply need to use [`Monthname()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) function to extract the month name from the date.
- This will work only when `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode is disabled.

Try:

```
SET sql_mode = ''; -- disable NO_ZERO_DATE mode
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m'));
```

---

As *@Felk* suggested in comments, if we need to get shortened month name, we can use [`Date_Format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function instead:

```
SET sql_mode = ''; -- disable NO_ZERO_DATE mode
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m'), '%b');
```

---

If you don't want to disable the `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode, then you can create any random date using the month and call `Monthname()`:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(CONCAT('2018-',3,'-1')); -- 3 is the input number
```

Comment: if you need the abbreviated name, you can use the `%b` specifier of [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format): `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b')`