# How to echo different string according to value of specific column of similar id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named 'payment' and the datas are:

```
id   client_id   month_id
1    99          10
2    99          11
3    99          12
```

Now in my front-end I want to show if the client 99 has 10 value in month_id echo 'October Paid'; if there is value 11 echo 'November Paid' and similar to all the months depending on the value of month_id.

How can I achieve this? I tried this:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM payment WHERE client_id = 99";

    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $data = $result->fetch_array();

    $mnthId = $data['month_id'];

    if ($mnthId = 11) {
        echo "November Paid";
    } else {
        echo "Unpaid";
    }
?>
```

But I always get the result of first row I mean October Paid. Other if condition is not working. Any help is deeply appreciated. TIA

Comment: The mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
MySQLi query : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
PDO query : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it . I think this works. Havent tested it,

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM payment WHERE client_id = 99";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['monthid']=="10") { echo "october paid"} 
    /* all months like this */
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you very much **Bijay** Your code did the trick. I m really a fool who overlooked this simple solution. Thanks again for enlighten me. And one more thing if you please update the query from `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`. I believe you have knowledge on this better than me.

Comment: The mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
MySQLi query : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
PDO query : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Oops sorry. Thank you azjezz for pointing that out. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather utilize [`Monthname()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) with [`Str_to_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function of the MySQL, to get month name directly from the query itself:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT *, 
                   MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month_id, '%m')) AS month_name 
            FROM payment 
            WHERE client_id = 99";

    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $data = $result->fetch_array();

    echo $data['month_name'] . " Paid";
?>
```

Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53213448/2469308 for additional details.

Comment: Thanks **Madhur** for your answer. But **Bijay's** answer seems more similar to what I want to achieve.